# How to access the folder of the downloaded artifact using properties?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have an artifact in Nexus containing a ZIP file, let's say

```
<groupId>com.ddd.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>mytool</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<classifier>bin</classifier>
<type>zip</type>
```

Now, I have another Maven project which depends on the above artifact so that I declare the above in the project's dependencies.

In the current project's workspace I download and unzip the content of the above ZIP archive using the command

```
mvn clean dependency:unpack-dependencies
```

which unzips the content to the folder *${project.build.directory}/dependency/mytool-2.1.0*.

**My question is** how can I access the subfolder *mytool-2.1.0* using Maven properties or any other variables?

Today it's version 2.1.0 but tomorrow it could be any other. In either case I'd like to have a method that works independent of it.

The background of the question is that in my build process I download several artifacts with ZIP files from Nexus, unzip them and then I want to copy them to other destinations which use other folder names.

Comment: How about using [`stripVersion`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html#stripVersion) to have a folder `${project.build.directory}/dependency/mytool`, without any version? Would that suit you?

Comment: Can you post your current configuration as well? By default `unpack-dependencies` unpacks everything in `target/dependency` without using subdirectories so I assume you're using `useSubDirectoryPerArtifact`?

Comment: My final solution was to create the zip archives without the base folder inside.